# WordPress - Error while uploading images or media in library or in pages error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been working on a WordPress site which worked fine in my localhost, but in the live server I wasn't able to migrate unfortunately, "All in one WP Migrate" plugin no longer worked. We've the domain registered under **HostGator** and caught up with a lot of issues.

[image]

When I resize and upload the lower resolution it's still the same, I found some links here and have enabled "imagick" but still getting the same issue.

Here is the error message.

> Post-processing of the image failed likely because the server is busy
> or does not have enough resources. Uploading a smaller image may help.
> Suggested maximum size is 2500 pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in incognito browser this error is temporary so don't very otherwise you just logout and again login and try it.

Answer (score 0):

I just switched the browser earlier I used Chrome, now I just logged in using FireFox and the issue resolved. I just have to clear my browser cache for WordPress to upload images. It took me a day finding answers, Thanks to **Nihar Fuerte** for your tip.